# css filters slow (for the HTML body)

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-filters

I am using HTML5 to create a game in google chrome, and was hoping to add options for brightness and contrast. What i have done so far is made a slider for each setting, which changes the filter for the HTML body like so

```
<p> Brightness: </p>
<input type="range" id="brightness_slider" value="100" step="1" min="40" max="160">
<p> Contrast: </p>
<input type="range" id="contrast_slider" value="100" step="1" min="40" max="160">
```

JavaScript:

```
var brightness = document.getElementById("brightness_slider"),
contrast = document.getElementById("contrast_slider");

brightness.addEventListener("input", function () {
    document.body.style.filter = "brightness(" + brightness.value + "%) contrast(" + contrast.value + "%)";
}, false);
contrast.addEventListener("input", function () {
    document.body.style.filter = "brightness(" + brightness.value + "%) contrast(" + contrast.value + "%)";
}, false);
```

However, as I am using the HTML5 SVG element, things get pretty slow (drops down to 10fps instead of 60fps).
I have tested with just having the CSS rule

```
body {
    filter: brightness(100%) contrast(100%);
}
```

which seems to also cause the lag. This makes me think that it is just the filters that are making it so slow, not inefficient code. Is there any way that I can make the page brighter and/or change contrast without this amount of frame-rate drop?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the value of the `step` attribute? A value of 1 might be too granular, thus generating too many events for the filter logic to handle.

Comment: @user3608792 I did, but I think that it's just the CSS filter itself causing the lag because even with the values left at 100%, it had the frame-rate drop

Comment: What does your SVG element look like? If you're generating large or complex graphics then there'e probably no good solution here other than moving to WebGL or similar.

Comment: @user3608792 by default it is simply `<svg id="canvas" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080"> <defs id="filters"> </defs> </svg>` with css`#canvas { height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0; background-color: #000; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; border: 0px;}`

Comment: @user3608792 but it has a lot of stuff going into it such as scrolling, fixed position rectangles (at least 15 normally, some closer to 100) and each rectangle has 4 dynamically updating shadows (one per edge)... however, without the CSS filter it does run at close to 60fps on a relatively old laptop so I do not think that it is that (but this does mean that the whole page is repainted every frame